# It is Impossible to Deactivate Page

Tags: aem

I'm trying to deactivate page in siteadmin. But deactivate buttons are not unavaliavle. A'm logged as Administrator. Why I have no right to perform this actions?

Screenshots:

1. popup menu

   [image: popup menu]
2. top menu

   [image: top menu]
3. status column

   [image: status column]

Comment: These buttons can be grayed out if the page is locked by another user. Can you check the `Status` column? It should be showing a padlock icon if the page is locked.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz status column is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check did you overlay the /libs/wcm/core/content/siteadmin/actions under /apps folder. Check out the properties on the action nodes [activate/deactivate] via access-control tab & see ACL via crxde. This blog can be helpful.

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/how-to-deny-access-to-site-admin-actions.html

[image]

Hope this will help.

Comment: I have the following access control in crx - http://i.imgur.com/LFVcXIF.png and i still unable to activate/deactivate pages

Comment: try restart your instance and access via admin. If still doesn't work then may be its causing by some other script.

Comment: The root of issue that /jcr:system/rep:privileges/jcr:all privilege does not aggregate crx:replicate, and 'admin' user privileges set to jcr:all by default.  I just added replicate permisions. Thanks for yours mention about  access-control